# how can i create a recording studio android app that looks life Fl studio

Tags: android

An app I could make beats and sing along the beats. an app that looks like fl studio or any other application that is used to make beats. please help

Answer (score -2):

A simple Google search gives this.

[Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)